# Using Pure Functions as Coordinates in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-mathematica

Does anybody know how to use pure functions in Locator in Wolfram Mathematica? For example, if I had a simple piece of code like this:

```
Graphics[
 Locator[
  Dynamic[fill, (fill = #) &]
  ]
 ]
```

There is an error because # is a stand in for a single number, not a pair of coordinates like is needed for Locator. I also tried this:

```
Graphics[
 Locator[
  Dynamic[fill, (fill = {#1, #2}) &]
  ]
 ]
```

Which yielded the same issue.

Comment: Also, the reason I'm not using a plain variable in the dynamic is so I can use that value for something else later. Dynamics are protected and cannot be operated on.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
fill = {1, 1};
{Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[fill, (fill = #) &]]], Dynamic[fill]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify tracking functions as Wolfram Language will automatically update the variable for you.  However, for this particular case you do need to initialise your `fill` variable.

Try

```
fill = {0, 0};
{Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[fill]]], Dynamic[fill]}
```

Hope this helps.